# How does "*.txt" regex work with ls command?

Tags: regex, shell, unix, ls

I have a file name

> atxt

and I am running this command

> ls *.txt

Ideally it should match . with 'a' and * with zero character, but it is returning files like

> a.txt, b.txt

Why is it that here ls is treating . as literal dot, rater than any character of regex.

Answer (score 7):

It's called [file globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29), not [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Although both support wildcards like "?", "*", they have different schemes.

For example, "a*" in glob matches any *filename* that begins with "a", but in regex it matches any *string* that has 0 or more of letter "a". Another difference is wildcard "?" and "*" in regex must have a preceding element, while it's unnecessary in globbing.

As for your last question, a dot "." has not special meaning in globbing, it's always a literal dot. To match exactly one unknown character in globbing, one could use "?".

Answer (score 4):

Its not REGEX, its [wildcard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character), where `*` means any character(s), before `.txt` that is why you are getting all the files with extension `.txt`

[Files and directories - WildCard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character#Files_and_directories)

> When specifying file names (or paths) in CP/M, DOS, Microsoft Windows
>   and Unix-like operating systems, the asterisk character ("*")
>   substitutes for zero or more characters. In Unix-like operating
>   systems, the question mark ("?") substitutes for exactly one character